# How to Handle XML string using VB.net where attribute have html value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to parse a xml file where attribute value have html data in vb.net throwing an exception  **'<', hexadecimal value 0x3c , is an invalid attribute character.**.

My sample XML is like this:

```
<root>
<control id="ctrl" type="paragraph" label="Declare" 
text="<b>Your idea has been posted successfully.Visit again to see updates on your ideas.</b>" visible="true" >
</control>
</root>
```

I had try to replace character < and > with &lt and &lg. 
but i can't fix this issue of parsing error.

Comment: u can see the text property has an html tag.. which is throw an exception during xml parsing in vb.net

Comment: Your XML needs to be properly well-formed. If not how do you expect it to parse? You need to fix whatever generated this.

Comment: Exception details
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3c , is an invalid attribute character.ls

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse this XML because it is invalid. Take a look at the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax).

`<` and `>` (and some other characters) have to be escaped (`&lt;` and `&gt;`) if not used as markup delimiters, or they have to be part of a CDATA section.

So, fix your XML, then you can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [html encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) the value of text as follows:

```
<root>
    <control 
        id="ctrl" 
        type="paragraph" 
        label="Declare" 
        text="&lt;b&gt;Your idea has been posted successfully.Visit again to see updates on your ideas.&lt;/b&gt;" 
        visible="true">
    </control>
</root>
```